# Android Process Function Not Working On Background

Tags: java, android

As you can see in the pictures, toast line is working properly but process function not working another activity.

This code line does not workking on background, only work on Activity.

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("input touchscreen tap 500 500");
```

My purpose is touch the different screen, EX:WhatsApp or any app.

```
    btndene.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.teamviewer.quicksupport.market");
                    startActivity(launchIntent);
             for(int i = 0; i<10; i++) {

                 try {
                     Thread.sleep(3000);

                 } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                 }

              update(i);
             }

                }

                private void update(final int i) {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            //txt.setText("Hello"+i);
                          //  komut = "input keyevent 30";
                            //calistir(komut);
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Bastin",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            try {
                                p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("input touchscreen tap 500 500");
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });

                }
            }).start();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to security reasons it wont work on other apps...You can use any UI automation frameworks like Robotium,Expresso to do this..

Comment: Thanks for reply :) well, can i run android shell command on background?

Comment: You should implement it using a thread inside a service...when activity goes into background,the code does not run...I would suggest to read more about android fundamentals here-http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals.html

Answer (score 0):

Try using [monkeyrunner](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkeyrunner_concepts.html) instead. It works with any app.